# Angular 4 password validation for particular missing character

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, passwords, character

I have a ***password*** field.Added ***validation*** in that like it ***allows all the characters except white space***.

**Let me show the code below what I'm using:**

> org-user.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group cav-form" [ngClass]="{'has-danger':!OrgUserForm.controls['password'].valid
          && !OrgUserForm.controls['password'].untouched}">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <span *ngIf="!OrgUserForm.controls['password'].valid ">*</span>
            <input type="password" (keypress)="restrictNumeric($event)" class="form-control" id="password" [(ngModel)]="formdata.password"   formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
```

> org-user.component.ts

```
public restrictNumeric(e) {
let input;
if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) {
  return true;
}
if (e.which === 32) {
  return false;
}
input = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
}
```

**What I want to do exactly here is I need validation according to what type of character user misses while entering password.**

> For Example: when typing something like **"Welcome123"**  in this case
>   user missed a **"special character"** so want to display message like
>   **"special character missed"**.

In short I want to display validation message dynamically according to the attributes missed in the password field.

**Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you validation is complex and you want to be in control of the message you can write custom validator that test all cases you want and return a desire message.

*password strength validator*

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export const PasswordStrengthValidator = function (
  control: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null {
  let value: string = control.value || "";

  if (!value) {
    return null;
  }

  let upperCaseCharacters = /[A-Z]+/g;
  if (upperCaseCharacters.test(value) === false) {
    return {
      passwordStrength: `text has to contine Upper case characters,current value ${value}`
    };
  }

  let lowerCaseCharacters = /[a-z]+/g;
  if (lowerCaseCharacters.test(value) === false) {
    return {
      passwordStrength: `text has to contine lower case characters,current value ${value}`
    };
  }

  let numberCharacters = /[0-9]+/g;
  if (numberCharacters.test(value) === false) {
    return {
      passwordStrength: `text has to contine number characters,current value ${value}`
    };
  }

  let specialCharacters = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
  if (specialCharacters.test(value) === false) {
    return {
      passwordStrength: `text has to contine special character,current value ${value}`
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-validation-password-strength)

Comment: I need the html page for reference, you have provided me only with ts file.

Comment: @D.Sridhar you can check stackblitz online example it 's contine everything complate angular example

Comment: Can you know about how to add ag-grid pagination tool-tip ??I have posted already one Question about that please see my Posts....